# In Python how to call subprocesses under a different user?

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

For a Linux system, I am writing a program in Python, who spawns child processes. I am using the "multiprocessing" library and I am wondering if there is a method to call sub-processes with a different user than the current one. I'd like to be able to run each subprocess with a different user (like Postfix, for example.)

Any idea or pointers ?

Comment: what call exactly are you using? with Popen you can use something like preexec_fn=lambda: os.setuid(100)

Comment: I use a multiprocessing.Process derivative. Setting the uid/gid seams to be a lack of its API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

modified python documentation example, I've added setuid in the function to be called, I'm not sure it fits to your needs and you may also need setgid, sedeuid setegid

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print title
    print 'module name:', __name__
    print 'parent process:', os.getppid()
    print 'process id:', os.getpid()

def f(name):
    os.setuid(1000)
    info('function f')
    print 'hello', name
    os.system('id')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Ah yes ! thanks ! I was searching something too complicated and your example will do the trick nicelly :D

Answer (score 2):

You could look in os.setpgid(pid, pgrp) direction.